# Matlab: How to fix Least Mean square algorithm code

Tags: matlab, least-squares

I am studying about Least Mean Square algorithm and saw this code. Based on the algorithm steps, the calculation of the the error and weight updates looks alright. However, it fails to give the correct output. Can somebody please help in fixing the problem? The code has been taken from:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35670-lms-algorithm-implementation/content/lms.m

```
clc
close all
clear all

N=input('length of sequence N = ');
t=[0:N-1];
w0=0.001;  phi=0.1;
d=sin(2*pi*[1:N]*w0+phi);
x=d+randn(1,N)*0.5;
w=zeros(1,N); 
mu=input('mu = ');
for i=1:N
   e(i) = d(i) - w(i)' * x(i);
   w(i+1) = w(i) + mu * e(i) * x(i);
end
for i=1:N
yd(i) = sum(w(i)' * x(i));  
end
subplot(221),plot(t,d),ylabel('Desired Signal'),
subplot(222),plot(t,x),ylabel('Input Signal+Noise'),
subplot(223),plot(t,e),ylabel('Error'),
subplot(224),plot(t,yd),ylabel('Adaptive Desired output')
```

EDIT

The code from the answer :

```
N = 200;
M = 5;
w=zeros(M,N); 
mu=0.2;%input('mu = ');
y(1) = 0.0;
y(2) = 0.0;
for j = 3:N
 y(j) = 0.95*y(j-1) - 0.195*y(j-2); 
end

x = y+randn(1,N)*0.5;
%x= y;
d = y;
for i=(M+1):N
   e(i) = d(i) -  x((i-(M)+1):i)*w(:,i);
   w(:,i+1) = w(:,i) + mu * e(i) * x((i-(M)+1):i)';
end
for i=(M+1):N
    yd(i) = x((i-(M)+1):i)*w(:,i);  
end
```

The weight matrix w which stores the coefficients are all zero, meaning that the LMS equations are not working correctly.

Comment: Where do you get the error? for N=10 and mu=0.1, the code works.

Comment: There is no syntax error. But, the graph of the Desired output is not even remotely close to the Actual signal. Secondly, when I apply this code to do parameter estimation of autoregressive model AR(2), I am not getting correct weights/parameters. My objective is to estimate parameters of AR(2) model where d(I) = 0.95*d(i-1) - 0.195*d(I-2); x = d+randn(1,N)*0.5; The output of the algorithm should give me w_estimates close to w_actual = [0.95 -0.195]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also do not find any mistake in your code. But I doubt that this algorithm is suitable for this kind of noise. You will get better results when using a filter of higher order (M in this case):

```
M = 5;
w=zeros(M,N); 
mu=0.2;%input('mu = ');
for i=(M+1):N
   e(i) = d(i) -  x((i-(M)+1):i)*w(:,i);
   w(:,i+1) = w(:,i) + mu * e(i) * x((i-(M)+1):i)';
end
for i=(M+1):N
    yd(i) = x((i-(M)+1):i)*w(:,i);  
end
```

Comment: sorry. my bad. I compare the formulas to the ones I found on wikipedia. There was y used and so I replaced it. I corrected it.

Comment: So, y = d the desired signal and x = noise added noisy signal?

Comment: Yes. Or Ground truth or some reference signal.

Comment: Ok, I ran your code but there is no result for the coefficients :( I have put up the code in my Question. Could you please see where I did wrong? Thank you for your continued support

Comment: Your input signal y (or d) is constantly zero. Also your weigth is initialized with zero. So error is always zero. Use different `y(0)`, `y(1)` values or set some initial weights: `w(:,M+1) = 0.1;`

Comment: Right, very stupid of me !! One last thing, as the model does not have time varying coefficients and is stationary, so is it possible for LMS to give the number of weights = number of non-zero lagged coefficients and not  matrix? Or will LMS always yield weights for each sample point since it is adaptive?

Comment: Sorry, I have no answer for that. I would suggest it will always yield weights for each sample point. You could try and average all weights `mean(w,2)`. Since your noise is zero mean, this could give you some good stationary coefficients.

Answer (score -1):

```
   N=input('length of sequence N = ');
    t=[0:N-1];
   w0=0.001;  phi=0.1;
   d=sin(2*pi*[1:N]*w0+phi);
   x=d+randn(1,N)*0.5;
    w=zeros(1,N); 
   mu=input('mu = ');
   for i=1:N
   yd(i)=w*x'; 
  e(i) = d(i) - w * x';
 for m=1:N
 w(m) = w(m) + mu * e(i) * x(m);
  end
 end
    subplot(221),plot(t,d),ylabel('Desired Signal'),
  sub plot(222),plot(t,x),ylabel('Input Signal+Noise'),
  subplot(223),plot(t,e),ylabel('Error'),
  subplot(224),plot(t,yd),ylabel('Adaptive Desired output')
```

What you were missing was the multiplication of error term in a single        iteration with each sample of input and separate update of  weights

Comment: You should try to explain a bit your answer and not give a code only answer.

Comment: according to lms weights vector update mechanism,present value of e(i) should get multiplied with every sample of input e.g( e(i)* x(n) ) will update w1(1st entry of weight vector) and e(i)*x(n-1) will update w2(second entry)....so if u have 1000 weights as in above example,then you need to update 1000 weights using error value of each iteration....and one change is storage of output of adoptive filter (yd) for every iteration.....at start of iterations this will not be a good approximation but after some updates of weights ,,,(yd) will become a better approximation of desired output.....